# How to make 3 displots appear in 1 row

Tags: python, seaborn, displot

I would like to create a row with 3 plots with seaborn displot, but now they appear one under another. I've tried to use the following code:

```
f, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15, 6))
```

which worked while using seaborn distplot, but here it only shows empty axes without plots.
My code:

```
sns.displot(df.col1, kde = True, height =3)
sns.displot(df.col2, kde = True, height =3)
sns.displot(df.col3, kde = True, height =3)
```

Comment: Use [`kdeplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html#seaborn.kdeplot), since `displot` is a figure-level interface?

Comment: `df = df.melt()` and `g = sns.displot(data=df, x='value', col='variable', kde=True)`